# who push params to stack when call function using _stdcall or _cdcel in C/C++?

Tags: visual-c++

We declare exports function using _stdcall when wirte exports functions in Dll. Then the cleaning stacking work will be implemented by function who is called. I want to know who push params to stack when call function using _stdcall or _cdcel in C/C++? 
  Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Unless you accept previous answers, most people will not answer any new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caller function always pushes the parameters onto stack, except for __fastcall.  Cleanup of the stack and the order parameters is governed by the calling convention.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions for a good writeup.

Comment: you may wanna reword the bit about __fastcall, as it still pushes args, except the first two (or three on borland) are in registers

Answer (score 0):

The calling function will except in the case of [naked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will push the parameters on the stack. How would the called function know what to push.